# C# webBrowser navigate to another page in pdf

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a C# winforms application that opens a pdf file in a webbrowser control. It opens to whatever page I want just fine however if I want to change page (go to a bookmark) the webbrowser stops working. I found [this article](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/525454-webbrowser-navigate-not-firing) which explains "Basically Webbrowser.Navigate(url) ONLY fires if the url changes. If it
doesn't change it uses a cached version of the web page." however I am calling navigate with a Uri, not a string url like this:

```
webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url));
```

My question is simply: how can I navigate to another page in the same pdf file, after I have opened the file in the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Of course I figure out the problem 2 mins after posting a question. I'll post my solution in hopes it helps someone else anyway;

So to make this work I used this workaround:

```
webBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
webBrowser.Hide();
webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
await Task.Delay(1000);
webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url));
webBrowser.Show();
```

Comment: Use `DocumentCompleted` event instead of   `await Task.Delay(1000);`

Answer (score 0):

This code may be useful to you.

```
public static void GetAllText(WebBrowser webBrowser,int toPageNum)
{
       webBrowser.Focus();
       for(int i = 0; i < toPageNum; i++)
            SendKeys.Send("{PGDN}");
}
```